# RegExp statements for two scenarios in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for two regExp statements that will

1. Determine if a text area is full of ONLY spaces with no other data (ie `" "`  or `"  "` n times)
2. Determine if pairs of hex values (ie A2, 81, 3B, etc.) are separated by anything other than 1 space.  Two spaces, three spaces, etc. between the values is invalid.

Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two should work:

1. `^\s*$`
2. `^([a-fA-F\d]{2}\s)*[a-fA-F\d]{2}$`

For future reference, please include more information about what you've tried in your question. Also some testcases (especially for the second expression) would be useful.

Comment: your first reg exp was exactly what I needed, and I came up with this reg ex to search for anything more than a double space does this work also? /([0-9a-f]{2})*([\s]{2})+([0-9a-f]{2})/i

Comment: I just fixed a typo I had in the second expression.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

- Empty or n spaces: `^\s*$`
- 1 or more spaces, it won't match empty: `^\s+$`

**2.**

- `/[0-9a-fA-F]{2}[\s]{2,}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/`

Comment: what does the ',' represent in {2,}?

Comment: The numbers between brackets specify the repetition:
{n} means n times
{n, n'} means from n to n' times
{n, } means at least n times

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be something similar to

- `^\s*$`

and

- `([\dA-F][\dA-F]\s[\dA-F][\dA-F])+`

Comment: because hex is 0-9, a-f `[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]\s[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]`